# Pandas column title and index

Tags: python, pandas

Does someone know how to display titles and indexes in the way described below?

in this sample example, we can see a display of title and boolean result`( code: df.isnull().any() )`
But what I need is titles and indexes display in this way.

```
e.g: 
State                                 False
District                              False
Persons                               False
Males                                 False
Females                               False
Growth..1991...2001.                  False
Rural                                 False
Urban                                  True
Number.of.households                  False
Household.size..per.household.         True
dtype: bool
```

Can someone help?
Thanks forward.

Comment: if I understand correctly you are searching for the `axis` keyword in the `any` statement?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `df.columns` to get the column labels of the dataframe and `df.index` to get the index.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this program by using `loc` property.
Let's create a dataset

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = np.arange(1,13)
data = data.reshape(3,4)
columns = ['Apple','Car','Sport','Food']
index = ['Alice','Bob','Emma']
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data,index=index,columns=columns)
df
```

Got the output as

```
Apple   Car Sport   Food
Alice   1   2   3   4
Bob 5   6   7   8
Emma    9   10  11  12
```

Then we can use loc property. The loc property is used to access a group of rows and columns by label(s) or a boolean array.

`.loc[]` is primarily label based, but may also be used with a boolean array. Mention the row you want.

```
df.loc['Bob',:]
```

Got the output

Output

```
Apple    5
Car      6
Sport    7
Food     8
Name: Bob, dtype: int64
```

You can access specific columns too.

```
df.loc['Bob',['Car','Food']]

Car     6
Food    8
Name: Bob, dtype: int64
```

For the index name

```
df.index
```

Output

```
Index(['Alice', 'Bob', 'Emma'], dtype='object')
```

For the columns

```
df.columns
```

Output

```
Index(['Apple', 'Car', 'Sport', 'Food'], dtype='object')
```